# Use of the forall construct in Stainless

Tags: scala

I'm trying to proof in Stainless that if two lists have the same contents and one list is bounded by x then the other list is also bounded by x. For doing so, I'm told to use the construct:

```
forall(x => list.content.contains(x) ==> p(x))
```

The lemma would be written (in a verbose way) as:

```
def lowerBoundLemma(l1: List[BigInt],l2: List[BigInt],x:BigInt) : Boolean = {
    require(l1.content == l2.content && forall(y => l1.content.contains(y) ==> y <= x))
    forall(z => l2.content.contains(z) ==> z <= x) because{
      forall(z => l2.content.contains(z) ==> z <= x) ==| l1.content == l2.content |
      forall(z => l1.content.contains(z) ==> z <= x) ==| trivial                  |
      forall(y => l1.content.contains(z) ==> y <= x)
    }
  }.holds
```

The problem is that I get the following errors:

```
exercise.scala:12:48: error: missing parameter type
require(l1.content == l2.content && forall(y => l1.content.contains(y) ==> y <= x))
```

Once I add the type to y I get this error (pointing to the left brace of the contains parentheses):

```
exercise.scala:12:81: error: ')' expected but '(' found.
require(l1.content == l2.content && forall(y : BigInt => l1.content.contains(y) ==> y <= x))
```

Any idea why this is happening?

I also tried the syntax `l.forall(_ <= x)` but I get errors when combining with constructs like `because` and `==|` of the type: because is not a member of Boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues you are facing are coming from the Scala compiler frontend to Stainless. In Scala, the syntax for a closure (with specified parameter type) is `(x: Type) => body` (note the extra parentheses!)

If you want to use `because` and `==|`, you'll have to add `import stainless.proof._` at the beginning of your source file.